# Saving facebook id as int or varchar?

Tags: mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My question is more advisory than technical.
I'm writing a Facebook app in which I am fetching some information about the user, including facebook_id.
I was wondering if I should keep the user id as INT or VARCHAR in the MySQL database?

Comment: IMAO you should switch the accepted answer to Gustav's.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Facebook uses **64-bit integers (bigint)** for their user ids. So you use Bigint UNSIGNED in MySQL.

["As a reminder, in the very near future, we will be rolling out 64 bit user IDs. We encourage you to test your applications by going to www.facebook.com/r.php?force_64bit and create test accounts with 64 bit UIDs."](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/226)

Edit: Facebook usernames is not the same thing as the user id. The username is of course varchar but will not be returned as the id.

Comment: Facebook says the user ID is a string. Perhaps they may switch to using alphanumeric. So use a string. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

Comment: For those of you reading this in order to determine the appropriate data type for Facebook ID's, use a **string**.  The JSON data structure returned uses a string data type (_e.g._, _not_ a numeric data type).

Comment: Their reference says `numeric string`, which means while the type is a string, the content is a number. So storing it as `UNSIGNED BIGINT` is fine, while storing as `varchar` will just make lookup and comparison more hassle. If FB does change to to `alphanumeric` which they haven't, there will be deprecation warnings and dev blog posts about it.

Answer (score 13):

Although unlikely, facebook could change the format of their ID's, so to make it future proof, I'd use a varchar.

Comment: Correct answer. Facebook says the user ID is a string. Perhaps they may switch to using alphanumeric. So use a string. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

Comment: @DougS Wrong answer: Gustav's one is correct, and it has been posted on the same day so it's not even a "they changed idea later" problem.

Comment: @Lohoris: Gustav's answer is unsafe. The Facebook doc I linked to states the user ID is a "numeric **string**". It is not a "bigint" as Gustav states in his answer. Your app will break once FB starts using alphanumeric ids, or if they return a numeric string that doesn't fit in a bigint. Much safer to store the ids as strings, just as Facebook defines it.

Comment: @Lohoris Anywhere that references the user ID as an `int` is outdated. It is definitely not an `int` as Facebook now has more user ID's (including biz page ID's, etc) than can even fit in an `int`.

Answer (score 9):

similar question to: [Facebook user_id : big_int, int or string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172126/user-id-big-int-int-or-string)

"I would not use a string. That makes comparisons painful and your indexes clunkier than they need to be."

Comment: Finally, I saved it as an unsigned int. Mostly because of the sorting and comparing. Take a look at link above.

Comment: @Sharon Haim Pour - You need to use bigint(20).  There are UID's that are longer than int(10).

Comment: @Phillip - Thanks for the notification. Did that.

Comment: Facebook says the user ID is a string. Perhaps they may switch to using alphanumeric. So use a string. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

Answer (score 5):

To quote facebook's upgrade notes regarding graph API v2.0 (effective May 2015):

> All IDs are strings. In v1.0, IDs were often large numbers.

Which (to me) implies that userids are not guaranteed to be numbers. In fact, facebook recommend that you use strings:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user#fields

> Name:id
> Description: id The id of this person's user account.
>
> This ID is unique to each app and cannot be used across different apps(...)
>
> type: string

Although I must admit I've never seen an alphanumeric id.

Comment: FWIW, after scouring the web, I was able to find a facebook product manager that admitted that uids were BigInt at the moment (Feb 2015) and that they have no plans on changing this for the V2.0 (May 2015), but it could change afterwards.

Comment: Now it says `numeric string` instead, which basically means they are having fun at us, I guess?

Answer (score 1):

Use BIGINT(64) to store Facebook User IDs.
Here you go: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/45/

Answer (score 0):

For new data types, as they are grahp obj ID, I believe it is safe to save them as BINT.
However, for old "id", e.g. pic, save them as string (you can easily see that they are in the format xxxxxx_xxxxxxxx)

Answer (score -4):

I'd use INT, because it's not so big. Searching in INT is faster and betterfor ordering

Comment: Searching for an int is faster if you're counting CPU cycles, but you're not likely to be able to measure the difference in any resolution that matters. Additionally, as @Rich S says, choosing the INT type locks you into what their ID looks like today and potentially causes problems in the future -- not only that FaceBook could change their ID format (they can), but also should the same code base be repeated for some other site with a non-pure-int ID format.

Comment: INT is too short for the number of users that facebook has now.

Comment: Yep. I've seen systems break because developers used INT for fb_uid's. It basically produced loads of duplicate "maxint"-numbers. Use BIGINT(64) UNSIGNED to be safe.